# Using VS2010 Profiler for memory measurement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I'm looking for using Built-in Visual Studio 2010 Profiler for measure memory
usage of my C# functions in a Windows application program, but I could not know how.

I searched the net about how to use VS2010 Profiler, but all links suggest using Silverlight which is related to Web application not Windows Application

Please if any one can tell me how to use VS2010 Profiler in C# Windows application, or send me a link or tutorials or any hint if something is missing, and thanks alot

Comment: what edition of VS 2010 are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version 10.0.303019.1 RTMRel, Professional Edition

Comment: please see my answer.  Built-in managed memory profiling is only present in Premium and Ultimate.  It's not available in Professional, sorry.

Answer (score 18):

(Full disclosure: I'm on the team that works on this feature.)

The VS2010 Profiler is only available in the Premium and Ultimate editions.  There are a number of resources for doing managed memory profiling.  Some are older, but still relevant:

- Blog: [The Object Allocation and Object Lifetime views](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2005/03/31/404173.aspx)
- Blog: [What code path is allocating the most bytes for a type?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrissc/archive/2008/06/14/where-are-the-most-bytes-for-a-type-being-allocated.aspx)
- Blog: [Using VSTS 2008 memory allocation profiling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2007/10/09/using-vsts-2008-memory-allocation-profiling.aspx)
- MSDN: [Collecting .NET Memory Allocation and Lifetime Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264934.aspx)

Object allocation profiling will show you where objects were allocated as well as aggregate statistics (size and count) for each type allocated.  Object lifetime shows you when objects were collected (Gen 0, 1, 2) as well as whether or not the object was in the Large Object Heap.

Comment: Does this kind of profiling work in mixed mode? I need to profile memory usage in an app that uses Microsoft C# and Intel C++ (via Intel Parallel Studio) together.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: Yes, VS memory profiling works for pure managed, managed with native code, and mixed-mode (e.g. C++/CLI) code. We will only collect data for the managed portions of your program. We do not currently do any native memory profiling.