# Why would this throw OutOfMemory?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I am experimenting with Marshal.AllocHGlobal and found puzzling that this code would not succeed, instead it throws an OutOfMemory exception:

```
namespace HAlloc
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // large file ~ 800MB
            string fileName = @"largefile.bin";
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

            // allocation succeeds
            IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)fileInfo.Length);

            // OutOfMemory exception thrown here:
            Marshal.Copy(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName), 0, p, (int)fileInfo.Length);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Why would it get an OutOfMemory when the AllocHGlobal call succeeded?

Comment: Split that line into two, and see if it's the `Marshall.Copy` throwing the exception or `File.ReadAllBytes` that's doing it. I'd bet the latter.

Comment: Doesn't it just mean that you do not have 2 times ~800 MB RAM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cause `File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)` also has to read the file which causes extra ~800 MB

Comment: +1. Possibly of interest - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742016/using-vs2010-profiler-for-memory-measurement. I also would recommend adding some try/catch statements around the block, and you could consider using a `using` statement when loading a large object like this into memory so it will always be disposed of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx