# Analysing memory iusses in a Visual Studio project C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, memory-management

I used to write programs in `Java` in `Eclipse` and I used to use a program, `Visual VM` to keep under control the usage of Heap, CPU and other performance variables, such as how many objects were created.

Now, I'm programming in `C#`, `Visual Studio`, and I would like to use a tool like 'Visual VM' for the same reason for my .NET project.

Does a such tool exist in the .NET world?
Thank you for your help, bye

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using VS2010 Profiler for memory measurement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742016/using-vs2010-profiler-for-memory-measurement)

Comment: Keep your VS version updated, VS2015 includes a built-in memory profiler.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly an answer to your question about whether or not such tools exist, but this should help you regarding memory management in .NET

[top 5 .NET memory management fundamentals](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/memory-management-fundamentals)

Sorry I couldn't comment my answer as I don't have 50 rep.

That or you can use the Visual Studio Profiler

Comment: It's not that difficult to gain enough rep to post comments.

Comment: I had literally created my account that day.